Unusual model fit and convergence metrics in Bayesian radiocarbon dating
In radiocarbon dating in archaeology, Bayesian methods are essentially the only game in town. The most commonly used software is OxCal, and while the general methods are fairly standard, its model diagnosis tools seem rather ideosyncratic. In particular, I'm referring to the agreement index, which is measuring the compatibility between the prior and posterior and is used as a model-fit statistic, and the convergence integral, which supposedly tests the effectiveness of the MCMC algorithm. Both metrics were defined in the paper accompanying the inaugural version of OxCal (Bronk Ramsey 1995, quote below from p. 429), but never theoretically motivated or connected to more typical model-fit or convergence statistics.

To incorporate the other information, OxCal uses a technique called Gibbs Sampling, which involves a large number of iterations. Buck et al. (1991), Buck, Litton and Smith (1992) and Buck, Litton and Scott (1994) describe this in some detail. I have made extensions to improve model consistency and convergence testing, which are particularly important for a program intended for general release. The test for model consistency is based on an agreement index $A$, which, for a prior distribution $p(t)$ (the probability distribution before the chronological model has been taken into account), and a posterior distribution $p'(t)$ (the distribution given the model), is defined as
$$
 A = \frac{\int p(t) p'(t) dt}{\int p(t) p(t) dt}
$$
A suitable acceptance threshold for this is ca. 60% for a similar level of discrimination as the $\chi^2$ test at 5%. An overall agreement index is also defined for the model as a whole, given by
$$
 A_{overall} = \left[ \prod_{i=1}^{n} A_{i} \right]^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}
$$
where $A_i$ is the agreement index for the $i$'th of n events. This has a similar threshold of 60%. Convergence tests are also needed to see if the Gibbs Sampling procedure is giving truly representative results. Such tests are performed by this program using an overlap integral $C$ between the accumulated probability distribution $P(t)$ and that for the last set of iterations $p(t)$
$$
 C = \frac{ \left( \int p(t) P(t) dt \right)^2 }{ \int P^2(t) dt \int p^2 (t) dt }
$$
Experience suggests that, if this integral is ever <95%, the algorithm is probably unstable and the results of the analysis should not be used. Another extension to the application of Gibbs Sampling to this type of problem is the inclusion of a method for wiggle matching in cases where the age gaps among items are known only approximately.

No further explanation is given in the paper or (to my knowledge) elsewhere. Does anybody know more about the statistical theory behind these metrics, and why they aren't used in other fields?
